# How to add a flag when running Code Runner in VSCode

Tags: vscode-code-runner

I would like to add the flag `-std=gnu++17` when running vscode-code-runner.

I try to change the settings.json file using the settings tab in VSCode, but that does not seems to work. Here is the settings.json I used:

```
{
        "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
        "python": "python",
        "perl": "perl",
        "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
        "go": "go run",
        "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && g++ -std=gnu++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The "c" line of the setting.json file needs to be changed as "cpp":

```
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=gnu++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
```

PS: Thanks to Jun Han @formulahendry for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code runner to run programs.

[image: Edit Executor Map settings.]

Add -std=c++17 to the following line and save the settings.json.

```
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

Thanks