# Despite having clang 15.0.0, vscode on mac os 14.1.1 my code isnt compiling according to newer c++ versions

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, vscode-tasks, delegating-constructor

```
(base) sushi@sushi C++ % cd "/Users/sushi/C++/" && g++ hello.cpp -o hello && "/Users/sushi/C++/"hello
hello.cpp:22:26: error: delegating constructors are permitted only in C++11
    Deep(const Deep &j): Deep(*j.data) {
                         ^~~~
1 error generated.
```

This is the error i'm getting while compiling my c++ code .
I've checked my clang and g++ version by going on the terminal and it displays this as the answer

```
(base) sushi@sushi ~ % clang --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
(base) sushi@sushi ~ % g++ --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

How can i fix this error . Not being able to use the newer features in c++ language is really messing my head up

In my tasks.json file i've specified c++17 as the argument so as the compiler compiles the code according to c++ 17 standards , where am i going wrong and how to correct it

Comment: *"In my tasks.json file i've specified c++17 as the argument"* I don't see `-std=c++17` in the command line, meaning you either didn't specify it correctly, or you did but you're not actually using `tasks.json` to run the code (e.g. the "code runner" extension ignores it).

Comment: How do i enable the "code runner" extension to run the code or where do I check if it is running the code or not ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the code runner and I wouldn't use it. *"where do I check if it is running the code"* What you press to run the code?

Comment: What I figured out is , clang uses c++98 by default hence why you need to change the arguments on the task.json file , but I don't know how to change that for code runner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111996/how-to-add-a-flag-when-running-code-runner-in-vscode

Comment: Thank you so much , I legit found that out couple minutes ago on GitHub ...